# What is the difference between "initial scope" and "requirements"?

Tags: object, architecture, scope, orientation, requirements

Thanks for taking the time to read this in advance.

I am writing an intermediate submission report for a project that I am re-engineering and my tutor wants a page summary, list of requirements (with justifications), an initial scope and a suggested architecture.

The main report will include analysis, design and implementation.

I've written everything apart from the initial scope. I'm really worried I'm going to repeat myself and I am unsure as to what the difference between my requirements and initial scope should be?

Here is an example of a requirement:

> The first option on the main menu will be “New Game”
>
> Current system: A user is automatically taken to a new game but they are restricted to     completing this game, before they can start a new one.
>
> New system: The option to start a new game will give users more flexibility if they do     not wish to complete the current one. The default level for games will be “low” to begin with, unless this is changed by the user.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirement is to start a new game from an ongoing game.

Where projects get into trouble is in limiting the scope.

For example does this requirement include:

- being able to go back to the original game and start where you left off?
- being able to start a third game when you are in the second
- when in the third game being able to go to the first without going via the second
- .....

The scope says something about what parts of the systems will be affected and how it will be solved.

The inital scope would be what functionality you are going to deliver in the first release.

Answer (score 1):

It's almost the same thing:

**Requirements** which by common definition represent something the system must do to fulfill a business need or contractual obligation.
**Initial Scope** is the features/products will be/desired delivered in the first release or planned currently.

Answer (score 1):

**Initial Scope** defines the edges of the project, in broad strokes what will be includes and what is excluded from the project or phase.
**Requirements** defines the detailed needs of those broad strokes.  Typically a project cannot have it's requirements captured before the edge is determined.